# Enter-PSSession causes a stack overflow exception

Tags: powershell

I have a batch file that contains a few commands to connect with Team Foundation Server 2012 through the command line utility TF.exe.

This batch file exists on our development server, and is designed to essentially "deploy" our website by getting latest from source control

The batch file works fine on the server, but calling the batch file remotely via PSSession causes some strange issues.

I frequently receive the error:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException
```

Or

```
Not enough storage available to complete this command...
```

There is plenty of resources available on the server in terms of available resources. I'm pretty new at powershell...what is it that I'm missing?

EDIT: Here's the command that worked for me:

```
set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell remote sessions have a default memory limit of 150MB.  The limits are configured in WinRM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Is that 150mb on the remote server, or on my local host?

Comment: That's 150MB on the remote server (the PSSession your connectied to).